# iOS HTTP Post: Request Successful Connection; Nothing happens

Tags: ios, http, post, webview, nsdata

I am trying to use a POST request for a User and Password form, to access a webapp beneath it, *so that users do not have to fill the fields or press the login key to access their webApps*. According to my NSLogs, The connection DidReceiveResponse, ConnectionDidReceiveData, and ConnectionDidFinishLoading, but I see no result in the simulator; **I go to the webview, and it shows the empty form, waiting for me to type my info... Not what I want. I want to bypass this form. What is/could be missing or blatantly wrong here?**:

**ViewDidLoad:**
...usr, pW, etc. are generated before *messageBody, etc...

```
NSString *messageBody = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"UsernameFieldName=%@&PasswordFieldName=%@", usr, pW];

NSData *postData = [messageBody dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];

 NSMutableURLRequest *theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:appURL];
[theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"Post"];

[theRequest setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
NSLog(@"%@", messageBody);

[theRequest setHTTPBody:[messageBody dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES]];

[theRequest addValue: messageBody forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
NSLog(@"%@", theRequest);

[NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest: theRequest delegate:self];
```

**Connection Methods:**

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection
didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse*)response
{
    NSLog(@"Connection DidReceiveResponse");

    webData = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection*)connection didReceiveData:(NSData*)data
{
    NSLog(@"ConnectionDidReceiveData");

    webData = [NSMutableData dataWithData:data];
}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection*)connection
{
    NSLog(@"Connection Did Finish Loading");

    [HelpWebView loadData:webData 
                 MIMEType:@"text/html"
         textEncodingName:@"UTF-8"
                  baseURL:nil];
}
```

**The following is Sangony's contribution**, which gets a little closer, but there is something else required to get to the webapp beneath the form.

```
 - (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection willSendRequestForAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
   //KeychainItemWrapper *keychainItem = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc] initWithIdentifier:@"key" accessGroup:nil];
   //NSString *usr = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecAttrAccount)];
   //NSString *pW = [keychainItem objectForKey:(__bridge id)(kSecValueData)];

    if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {
    NSLog(@"received authentication challenge");
    NSURLCredential *newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"?username"
                                                                password:@"?password"
                                                             persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
//        NSURLCredential *newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", usr]
//                                                                    password:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", pW]
//                                                                persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
    NSLog(@"Credential created");
    [[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
    NSLog(@"Responded to authentication challenge");
}
    else {
    NSLog(@"Authentication failure");
}}
```

**Update**
I have tested the above methods here: 
http://www.posttestserver.com/

The keys and values are what I need for my form. The problem lies in the form/site/server. Not sure where to go from here. Any suggestions on where to start looking from here would be fantastic.

Comment: I am having the same problem now! Did you ever figure out the correct solution to your problem? Thanks for your time!

Comment: Its a while ago, but I think it turned out the web app was the problem, as sangony mentioned below.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this code:

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
{
if ([challenge previousFailureCount] == 0) {
NSLog(@"received authentication challenge");
NSURLCredential *newCredential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithUser:@"?username"
                                                            password:@"?password"
                                                         persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistenceForSession];
NSLog(@"Credential created");
[[challenge sender] useCredential:newCredential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
NSLog(@"Responded to authentication challenge");    
}
else {
NSLog(@"Authentication failure");
}
```

Comment: I think that is getting somewhere...This method logs correctly all the way to "Responded to authentication challenge"... Though nothing happens in my simulator. Is there anything else that must be done to push this data and push through this form in my web view?

Comment: If you got to "Responded to authentication challenge" that means your user name, password was accepted by your server. Upon successful login, what is suppose to happen next in your server/app?

Comment: It is supposed to load a webapp which comes after successful form login.

Comment: Try sending a simple HTML page instead. That way if you see the page, you know it's an issue with the webApp.

Comment: You mean to use a simpler HTML form/page to test on? If that's the case, is something like this: http://httpbin.org/ something that you would pursue?

Comment: OK... I found http://www.posttestserver.com/ ... The username and password keys and values match the corresponding field names and required values of my site, so... its got to be some other issue... not sure where to go from here.

Comment: Without knowing all the details of your project, it sounds like the webApp is the problem. I would look into that for right now.